# truth table,7-segment display

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image]

1. Write  the system truth table
2. Write a Boolean expression for each of the LED segments (a...g) and the BELL signal as a function of the inputs L and B.

Here are my attempts at it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework without any attempt at a solution.

Comment: Marwa, we don't want to ruin your learning experience by doing your homework for you. Can you show us what you have tried and where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: I really tried to solve it and I reach to an answer I just want to make sure that my truth table is correct ..

Comment: Then post your result and ask if it is correct.

Comment: Then edit your question and add your truth table, so it can be reviewed.

Comment: I did, it could be wrong but this because I am a first year electrical engineering student and doctor never talk about this and this task for presentation

Answer (score 1):

The column for f is definitely wrong.  (Look where it is connected.  It can only have one value, ever.)

Columns a d e g are also wrong.  They should always all have the same value (correct) and it should be the inverse of L.

Column b is wrong.  It is the AND result of inverse L and inverse B.  Your column b has all values the same, which can't be correct.

Column c is incorrect as well.  It is the result of inverse B OR L.

You are missing a column for the BELL signal.

Comment: I tried to fix my answer but I don't how can I combine all these in one truth table and what is the value of f. Any advice please??

Comment: Vcc is the positive power supply, so anything connected to it is high (1.)

Comment: You have values for all the inputs and all the outputs.  Make a table (like your first one) and put the values in the proper places.

Comment: regarding Boolean expressions should I write 8 expression for segment a =L' and same thing to segments d,e,g. however segment b will be L'.B' , segment c will be L+B'  and last expression for the led which is L+B or it must be one expression for all